# pyramid ZopeTransactionExtension with celery: how can I commit transaction immediately without keep transaction after web request?

Tags: transactions, celery, pyramid

Here my situation.

I am building a RESTful webservice that recieve data from client, then create an Event from this data, then I want to push this new Event to celery to process it asynchrously.

I use pyramid to build RESTful webservice, and pyramid_celery to make pyramid & celery work together.

Here my view's source code:

```python
# views.py
# This code recive data from client, then create a new record Event from this

posted_data = schema.deserialize(request.POST.mixed())

e = Event()
e.__dict__.update(posted_data)
DBSession.add(e)
transaction.commit()

print "Commited #%d" % e.id # code mark 01
fire_event.delay(e.id) # fire_event is a celery task
logging.getLogger(__name__).info('Add event #%d to tasks' % e.id)
```

and here's my task's source code:

```python
# tasks.py
@celery.task()
def fire_event(event_id):
    e = DBSession.query(Event).get(event_id)

    if e is None:
        return

    print "Firing event %d#%s" % (event_id, e)
    logger.info("Firing event %d#%s", event_id, e)
```

If I use default code from pyramid's alchemy scaffold, an exception will be raised at *code mark 01* line. The exception like that :

```
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Event at ...> is not bound to a Session; ...
```

from [ZopeAlchemy document](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.sqlalchemy), to avoid this exception I configure the DBSession like that:

```python
# models.py
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
                extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(keep_session=True)
            ))
```

Now my problem is the pyramid keep transaction with my MySQL server after my RESTful request finish. When the RESTful request finish, I go to MySQL Server and run command:

```
SHOW engine innodb status;
```

and from its result, I see this:

```
--TRANSACTION 180692, ACTIVE 84 sec
MySQL thread id 94, OS thread handle 0x14dc, query id 1219 [domain] [ip] [project name] cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 180693, sees < 180693
```

that means Pyramid still keep the connection, it's ok but Pyramid starts a transaction also, it's a problem. This transaction can make me in a lock when I try to use another tool to access my MySQL Server.

My question is :

**How can I make Pyramid close the transaction as soon as RESTful request finish. If I cann't, is there another solution for my situation?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Celery maintains an illusion of "transparently" running your code as a task - you decorate your function with `@task`, then use my_function.delay() and everything magically works.

In fact, and it's a bit tricky to realize, your code runs in a completely different process, possibly on another machine, possibly minutes/hours later, and there is no Pyramid request/response cycle exist in that process, so ZopeTransactionExtension can not be used to automatically commit transaction in the working process when request finishes - because there is no request, just one long-running worker process.

So it is not Pyramid leaving unfinished transactions hanging - it's your worker process. The transaction is started by SQLAlchemy when you call `e = DBSession.query(Event).get(event_id)` and never finishes.

Here I wrote a longer answer to a similar question with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16346587/320021 - the point is to use a different session for your worker process

Another thing is that it is better to avoid using `transaction.commit()` in your Pyramid code at all because of the objects expiring and other ugliness. In pyramid it is possible to invoke a function after the request finishes - I wrote a function which registers a callback which invokes a celery task from there:

```
from repoze.tm import after_end
import transaction

def invoke_task_after_commit(task_fn, task_args, task_kwargs):
    """
    This should ONLY be used within the web-application process managed by repoze.tm2
    otherwise a memory leak will result. See http://docs.repoze.org/tm2/#cleanup
    for more details.
    """
    t = transaction.get()  # the current transaction

    def invoke():
        task_fn.apply_async(
            args=task_args,
            kwargs=task_kwargs,
        )

    after_end.register(invoke, t)
```

(I removed a lot of irrelevant code from the function so there might be typos etc. Treat as pseudocode)

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm new to Python & Pyramid. I got this error when try to implement your function:

        from repoze.tm import after_end
    ImportError: No module named tm

I know that I'm missing some packages from that. If you have another tutorial or answer, please introduce it to me, I'm still a newbie. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you, you help me alot. I changed a bit from your answer, I attach to SQLAlchemy events instead of repoze's. Then I use different DBSessions for pyramid & celery. I solved my problem, thanks a lot.